# Products url 301 permanently moved to new products url in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have create a magento ecommerce website. In start products url it does work with category url. So google is crawling all product's url with category url.
Now i have removed category url from products url using admin settings here:

```
System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization
```

and I set `Use Categories Path for Product URLs to No`.

by using this category url are removed from `products url` but old url still comes on google crawling and open.

I want to redirect old url to 301 permanent redirect on new url, but I have not an idea about this.
Please suggest and provide me solution of this problem.

Comment: I don't thing there is anyway instead of `.htaccess` file but it can be painful if you got lot of products. I will suggest use `meta canonical` for your `product urls`

Comment: You can use Magentos URL rewrite management to add individual rewrites for each of the old urls. It's not difficult to write something to automate this..